# Why is the hash of a blob in JS different from the hash obtained when using sha256sum in the terminal?

Tags: javascript

I am hashing a blob by reading it first using FileReader API in Javascript. The library I am using is [JSHashes](https://github.com/h2non/jshashes).

```
var fileReaderForHash = new FileReader();
fileReaderForHash.readAsArrayBuffer(zipBlob);
fileReaderForHash.onload = () => {
  var zipFileHash = new 
  Hashes.SHA256().hex(fileReaderForHash.result);
  console.log(zipFileHash);
  postRef.update({hash:zipFileHash});
}
```

But when I do "sha256sum zipfile.zip" in the terminal the hash obtained doesn't match with the one that was logged. I have also tried all other read methods of the FileReader API. What should I do differently?

Comment: What happens if you use `loadend` instead of `load`?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation provided by **t.niese** is correct. I am posting its solution.

I solved this using the sha256sum library from [GitHub](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256).

Here is the code:

```
          .....
          // import the library
          var hash = sha256.hex(zipArrayBuffer);  // input arraybuffer
          console.log(hash);  // displays hash
          zipBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(zipBlob)]);  // convert to blob for reading
          .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this "answer" does not give a solution but it explains why this does not work.

The current version of the JSHashes library (1.0.7) requires a string as input, but you provide an `ArrayBuffer`.

Internaly when `hex` is called, this code is executed, where `s` is your ArrayBuffer and `utf8` default to `true`:

```
function rstr(s, utf8) {
  s = (utf8) ? utf8Encode(s) : s;
  return binb2rstr(binb(rstr2binb(s), s.length * 8));
}

function utf8Encode(str) {
  var x, y, output = '',
    i = -1,
    l;

  if (str && str.length) {
    //  .... some other code
  }

  return output;
}
```

And `utf8Encode` will always return an empty string for an ArrayBuffer because it has no `length` property. Even if you change `utf8` to `false` the problem will persist because it will still expect a string and fail at another place because of the missing `length`.

And the sha256 for the empty string is `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` and thats the sha256 you will get for every file.

Comment: You are right. I am willing to move to another library if that would fix it. Any ideas on how I can get those two hashes to match?

Comment: @aswin1999 no sorry. I have never required to calculate the hash client side, so I can't suggest an alternative.

Comment: What about the server side? Can I do it then?